# Something Similar to Windows 7 Application Thumbnail Previews (see details) in my C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx#id0420081

^ I am looking for that kind of feature, but I want it in my C#/WPF application. I want the previews slightly larger than thumbnails as well. Any help would be great!

Comment: This appears to be a horizontally oriented items control with templated buttons.  Was your question on how to compose it?  Or the Xaml itself?

Answer (score 0):

You might find something useful in this library: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack